# Does html() really replace html code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html code like this,

```
<form action="abc.html" method="post">
   <div id = "result">
      <input type="hidden" value="1" name="banner">
   </div>
</form>
```

Then I get some Jquery code to replace the content in this div,

```
var temp = "<input type='hidden' value='1' name='banner'>"
$(".result").html(temp);
```

Then I submit the form and I find there are two values in form.banner, 
**form.banner=1,1**

Do I wrong? Or I have to use something to clear the data first then use html()?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Having two input fields with the same name would not result in the form sending two values, so that's not your problem. Show the code related to both sending and receiving the form, the problem is somewhere there.

Comment: .result is a selector for a class not an id.

Comment: use "#result" instead

Comment: @Juhana: *"Having two input fields with the same name would not result in the form sending two values,"* Yes it does.

Comment: @FelixKling Huh. I've never noticed that because the receiving end always overwrites one with the other.

Comment: $(".result") was my writing issue. The original code is $("#result"). And @FelixKling, I agree with you. It does.

Comment: @Juhana: Yeah, PHP does that. Python is able to handle it fine though.

Comment: I am using Coldfusion....And my reputation is low enough! Do not downvote please...

Comment: If the original code really is `$('#result').html(temp)`, and if there's only the one `#result` in the page, then there should not be two inputs present. in that `div`. Set a breakpoint after `.html(temp)` and see what is in the DOM. I think something else is going on that's not in your question.

Comment: If you don't want downvotes, show more of your code. What you have in the question now is not enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I still do not know whats wrong today but I figure out a solution. Initially I set empty in the div, and then I use Jquery to add  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="banner"> in the div. Third, I use another piece of Jquery to add/remove new content in the div. After I submit the form, the result turns out good, form.banner = 1

Answer (score -1):

Replace .result with #result. You're trying to target a class, but your div contains an id.

Answer (score -2):

When you use a $(".result").html(temp), it will match class="result".
You want to use $("#result").html(temp) to match id="result".

Comment: It was my writing issue on this post. The original code is $("#result")